# How to get a key from kafka message in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Here is my kafka listener:

```
    @KafkaListener(
            containerFactory = "kafkaChangeClientPhoneListenerContainerFactory",
            topics = "${kafka.topic.changeClientPhone}"
    )
    public void consume(ChangeClientPhoneEvent changeClientPhoneEvent) {
        //TODO
    }
```

Here are the topic settings:

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> changeClientPhoneConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(saslConsumerConfig(changeClientPhoneConsumerConfig()));
    }

    private Map<String, Object> changeClientPhoneConsumerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ChangeClientPhoneEventDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommitFlag);
        return props;
    }
```

I need to get the "siebel-id" param which comes as a header/key:
[image]

How to get it as a String var?

Comment: I suggest reading the spring-kafka documentation... It tells you multiple ways to get the full message rather than only the value. For example, have you tried adding a String parameter to the listener method? What happens when you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#consumer-record-metadata).

> Finally, metadata about the record is available from message headers. You can use the following header names to retrieve the headers of the message:

> `KafkaHeaders.OFFSET`

> `KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY`

> `KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC`

> `KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID`

> `KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP`

> `KafkaHeaders.TIMESTAMP_TYPE`

> The following example shows how to use the headers:

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "qux", topicPattern = "myTopic1")
public void listen(@Payload String foo,
        @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY, required = false) Integer key,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) long ts
        ) {
    ...
}
```